# What is the difference between ls [13] and ls {1,3}?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I created three files in my directory using the command `touch inv{1..3}.txt`. Now I used two commands and their output is pretty much the same. Those two commands are `ls inv[13].txt` and `ls {1,3}.txt`.

So how are these two different? How are square brackets different compared to braces? Also I was googling for "linux [..]", but couldn't find anything, so could I know as to what these things are called in linux terminology?

Thanks

Comment: The name for this is "filename expansion" or "globbing".

Comment: Which of these is filename expansion or globbing? Is it the square bracket([..]) or the flower bracket({..})?

Comment: Visit [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) for `{}` and [Filename Expansion > Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for `[]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `{}` is called brace expansion. It has two forms: `{x..y}` and `{x,y}`, replace `x` and `y` with any alphabetic or numeric value.

  In the first form, `{x..y}` will be expanded to all values from `x` to `y`, inclusive. For example, `{2..5}` will be expanded to `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`.

  In the second explicit form, `{x,y}` will be expanded to only `x`, `y`. For example, `{2,5}` will be expanded to `2` and `5`.

  If no expansion is possible, the pattern is treated literally e.g. in `{a..3}`.

  Important thing to note is that the brace expansion will be done (if possible) irrespective of any file match, while in file creation/matching.
- `[]` is known as a pathname expansion (or globbing) pattern. Unlike brace expansion you can only use it while matching filenames, it will be treated literally if you use it while creating files.

  It has two forms: `[xyz...]` and `[x-y]`.

  In the first form, it will match any single character inside the square brackets separately I.e. each character is treated individually. So for `[25].txt` it will match a file named `2.txt` or `5.txt` in the current directory, while for `[245].txt` it will match any file named `2.txt` or `4.txt` or `5.txt`.

  In the second form, a range expansion is done first before matching individually, if possible otherwise treated literally. So for `[2-5]. txt`, it will match any file named `2.txt` or `3.txt` or `4.txt` or `5.txt`. If the range can't be expanded, it will treated literally e.g. in case of `[a-3].txt`.

---

An important behavioral difference between these two is when there are more patterns to match while less actually is matched. As the brace expansion is done no matter what, it will show error that certain file(s) does not exist while pathname expansion will match whatever possible without any error for the rest:

```
$ ls {1..4}.txt
ls: cannot access 4.txt: No such file or directory
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls [1-4].txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

---

**Portability Note:**

The `[]` pathname expansion operator is defined by POSIX hence portable among Bourne shell and derivatives.

The brace expansion, `{}`, is not defined by POSIX hence is not portable among all shells. For example,  `dash` (`sh` in Ubuntu) does not have this. It was borrowed from `csh` and will work on certain shells only e.g. `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`, `fish`. Make sure the shell you are using supports this before implementing.

---

**Example:**

```
$ touch {1..3}.txt

$ ls {1..3}.txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls {1,2,3}.txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls {1..4}.txt
ls: cannot access 4.txt: No such file or directory
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls {a..3}.txt
ls: cannot access {a..3}.txt: No such file or directory
```

---

```
$ ls [123].txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls [1-3].txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls [1-4].txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ ls [a-3].txt
ls: cannot access [a-3].txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: One should avoid relying on the behavior of `[` `]` expansion when there are no matches because that can be different depending on shell configuration. If you want to use `[` or `]` in a filename, it should be quoted in your commands. It is also worth noticing the difference between `{13..79}` and `[13-79]`. The first will produce all numbers in the range from `13` to `79`, the second will match the characters `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, and `9`.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, that's what `nullglob` (or similar) is for. About the `[13-79]` matching, i think i mentioned clearly in my answer about the per character behavior of []`.

Comment: @heemayl  I think it would be also worth mentioning that ` {1..3}` form is bashism. This won't work in dash. I think `ksh` has this feature, but not it's more modern flavors, like mksh and pkdsh

Comment: @Serg Added the portability note.

Answer (score 7):

The key difference between the two forms is illustrated here:

```
$ ls inv[15].txt
inv1.txt
$ ls inv{1,5}.txt
ls: cannot access 'inv5.txt': No such file or directory
inv1.txt
```

`inv[15].txt` is a glob and will expand the a list of matching files on your file system.  This is *pathname expansion*.

`inv{1,5}.txt` expands to `inv1.txt` and `inv5.txt` regardless of what files are actually on your file system.  This is *brace expansion*.

Comment: The other key difference is that you can write `ba{con,tman}` and there's no equivalent using square brackets. IOW, brace expansion isn't only for single characters.